# Runtime.exec command not working

Tags: java, wget, runtime.exec

I have a java application that downloads a file from a web service using wget. When executing the command through java it returns with: "wget: not an http or ftp url:"
When i execute the command directly it runs without problems. Here is my code:

```
try {
        Debug.println("Starting copy of "+srcFile+" to "+destFile);
        String command = "wget -O " + destFile + " \""+ srcFile +"\"";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        int exitCode = p.waitFor();

        if(Debug.isDebugMode())
        {
            Debug.println(command);
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

            String s;
            while((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Debug.println(s);
            }
        }
        Debug.println("Finished with code: " + String.valueOf(exitCode));
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
```

And this is the output:

```
24/04/2013 10:11:05 Starting copy of stoppenmetroken.webcolors.local/service/track?track=3b1ac68a288345c183a08c714901a398&mac=089000A09090 to /opt/byato/data/song/3b1ac68a288345c183a08c714901a398
24/04/2013 10:11:05 wget -O /opt/byato/data/song/3b1ac68a288345c183a08c714901a398 "stoppenmetroken.webcolors.local/service/track?track=3b1ac68a288345c183a08c714901a398&mac=089000A09090"
24/04/2013 10:11:05 wget: not an http or ftp url: "http://stoppenmetroken.webcolors.local/service/track?track=3b1ac68a288345c183a08c714901a398&mac=089000A09090"
24/04/2013 10:11:05 Finished with code: 1
```

ps: i removed the http:// part of the output because i dont have enough reputation points -.-

What am i missing?

Comment: Start by using `ProcessBuilder` over `Runtime#exec`.  It allows you to passing the parameters as individual parameters rather then having to try and build a String, taking care of things like quotes

Comment: `Runtime#exec(String[])` avoids the need to build the command into a single string, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this:

```
String command = "wget -O " + destFile + " \""+ srcFile +"\"";
```

is the problem. When you run in a shell, the quotes around the URL will be removed. However when you run via Java you're not running via a shell and your URL starts with `"http...` (look closely at the error message).

If you don't want `Runtime.exec() t`o parse and split your arguments then you might consider [the variant that takes individual arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29). A more efficient solution still would be to download using [HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).

Comment: Solved it using: 
String[] command = {"wget", "-O", destFile, srcFile};

Now it runs. Thnx

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to execute the command like this :

**Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c "+command);  //for linux**

or

**Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c "+command);  //for Windows**

Sometimes we need to explicitly invoke Linux shell or command prompt.

Hope this will work.